# Authentification Scope Problems with Google Analytics API in Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, google-analytics-api

I am setting up a Shiny Dashboard to get unsampled reports through the Google Analytics Report API. This is my first Shiny-Projekt so maybe the solution to my problem is very simple. Unfortunately i can not find anything which would help me. So welcome to my very first question on Stackoverflow :).

I already set the authentication scope to the highest and set an client web id in an own projekt. Basicly everything which is best practiced in all found tutourials (Big Respect to Mark Edmondson!).

```
    library(shiny) # R webapps
    library(googleAuthR) # auth login

# refresh authenticiaction token and set client scope

gar_set_client(web_json = "CLIENTID-JSONFILE", scopes = ("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics"))

library(googleAnalyticsR) 

####################
# Shiny: USER INTERFACE
####################

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Authorization Login-Button
  googleAuth_jsUI("auth", login_text = "Log In"),   

  # Drop-Down Menue: Account, Property, View
  column(width=12, authDropdownUI("auth_dropdown", inColumns = FALSE)), # Modul Auswahl des Views 1 von 2
  dateRangeInput("datepicker", NULL, start = Sys.Date()-30),

  # The dimension selector (dropdown) 
  selectInput("dim", label = "Please select at least one dimension", 
              choices = dimension_options, 
              selected = c("date","hour","minute"),
              multiple = TRUE),

  # The metric dropdown
  selectInput("metric", label = "Please select at least one and maximal ten metrics", 
              choices = metric_options, 
              selected = "sessions",
              multiple = TRUE),

  # Download Button 
  downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
                 )




####################
# Shiny: SERVER LOGIK
####################

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # get authorizatin token
  auth <- callModule(googleAuth_js,"auth") 

  # Accountliste: 
  ga_accounts <- reactive({
    req(auth())
    with_shiny(
      ga_account_list,
      shiny_access_token = auth())
    })

  # Views: Greift auf die Accountliste zu
  view_id <- callModule(authDropdown, "auth_dropdown",
                        ga.table = ga_accounts)

  # Daten abrufen
  ga_data <- reactive({
    req(view_id())
    req(input$datepicker)
    req(input$dim)
    req(input$metric)

    with_shiny(
      google_analytics,
      view_id(),
      date_range <- input$datepicker,
      metrics <- input$metric, 
      dimensions <- input$dim,      
      max = -1, #kein Sampling
      shiny_access_token = auth() 
    )
  })

  # Daten downloaden
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("ViewID_",view_id(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file){
      write.csv2(ga_data(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    })


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The Problem is, that i get the following Error-Code despite the Code worked a few days before:

```
Warning: Error in : API returned: Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

  93: stop
  92: checkGoogleAPIError
  91: _f
  89: cachedHttrRequest
  88: memDoHttrRequest
  87: f
  86: gar_api_page
  85: f
  84: with_shiny
  83: <reactive:ga_accounts> [S:/GA_Report_Shiny/shinyapp_v0.R]
  67: ga.table
  66: <reactive>
  50: pList
  44: <observer>
   1: runApp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit" to list GA accounts, which is what is needed for the `ga.table` function above.

Comment: Thank you very much! My Failure was that i thought the Google Analytics Reporting API v4 is the newer version of the Google Analytics API v3 and the scopes from the v3 Version are now bundled in the v4 Version. (List of Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#analyticsv3)

Answer (score -1):

The very first Shiny-Project you need to understand Google Analytics Report API. See below I mention API console support two type of credentials. OAuth 2.0 and API Keys.

```
    // Create the service.
            var service = new DiscoveryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    ApplicationName = "Discovery Sample",
                    ApiKey="[YOUR_API_KEY_HERE]",
                });

// Run the request.
            Console.WriteLine("Executing a list request...");
            var result = await service.Apis.List().ExecuteAsync();

            // Display the results.
            if (result.Items != null)
            {
                foreach (DirectoryList.ItemsData api in result.Items)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(api.Id + " - " + api.Title);
                }
            }
```

You can also refer [them](https://expertiseexchange.com/#/MasterPageComponent/TopicDetails/11) for a more complete solution.

Comment: This does not answer the question of @dwightkschrutelll. Please provide a complete answer, instead of linking to another help page. Or, if you think the question does not belong here or is a duplicate, report the question accordingly.

Comment: This is not even the same coding language as the question